# Problem with running sata hdd with pata hdd

Tags: hard-drive, sata, pata

There's a problem when I try to connect my pata hdd(slave) with the sata hdd(primary). The computer sometimes detects the drive and sometimes not. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the drive configuration to user defined rather than auto detect.